# Is this jumbled image due to difference between Matlab and Python slicing?

Tags: matlab, python, image-processing, jpeg

When I import an image from Matlab I get the following jumbled image

[image]

rather than the (224x224x3 RGB) image of a single elephant I expected

[image]

I write the image from Matlab as a binary file

```
function save_bin(filename, input_image)
  r = input_image(:,:,1); % dump image for input to python
  g = input_image(:,:,2);
  b = input_image(:,:,3);
  fid = fopen(filename,'wb');
  fwrite(fid, r(:), 'float32');
  fwrite(fid, g(:), 'float32');
  fwrite(fid, b(:), 'float32');
  fclose(fid);
endfunction
```

And read it back into Python as follows

```
m_resized = np.reshape(np.fromfile('m_resized.bin', dtype=np.float32),(224,224,3))
image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(m_resized), 'RGB')
image.show()
```

I've investigated the slicing differences creating a 3x3x3 tensor in Matlab and importing it and there's a fundamental difference in the slicing syntax between Matlab Python but this alone doesn't explain  what's going wrong

Any ideas?

Note: The reason I'm using a binary format rather than a jpg image is that I want to compare a Matlab CNN model to a Numpy implementation at each stage and using an image is an intelligible means of comparison rather than comparing lots of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the order in which pixels are accessed in Matlab is different from that in Python

The problem is resolved by specifying the order in the numpy [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function to be the same as that of Matlab using the order='F' flag

Where ‘F’ means to read / write the elements using Fortran-like index order, with the first index changing fastest, and the last index changing slowest

```
def display_image(input_image) :
  image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(input_image), 'RGB')
  image.show()

m_resized = np.reshape(np.fromfile('../resnet50_matlab/m_resized.bin', dtype=np.float32),(224,224,3), order='F')

display_image(m_resized)
```

This results in the correct image being displayed as shown in the image below

[image]

Rather than the mangled image displayed using

```
m_mangled = np.reshape(np.fromfile('../resnet50_matlab/m_resized.bin', dtype=np.float32),(224,224,3))

display_image(m_mangled)
```

[image]